# Django - Creating & searching a custom user model

Tags: python, django

I have created my own custom user model, to override the built in one.

```
# models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Originally, when I wanted to search the database, i would import `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, and then do..

```
# create new user
new_user = User()

# Search existing users
Users.objects.find()
```

My question is, in a world where im now using my own custome user model, how do I do the equivalent?  Do i have to `from model import CustomUser` and then use that instead?

Thanks,

Comment: This should help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instead of importing the `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.models` you can just import your own User model and work with that.

Make sure that if you want to add foreign keys to your custom user model, that you use that model again. If you're building a reusable Django app it's a better approach to set your foreign to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, for example:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```